# NodeJS - ExpressJS - Mongo - Count Number of Documents Based on a Filter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to get a count of documents based on my search criteria. Basically, each user on the site creates a handful of documents and I record the username of the person with each document in the collection.

I want to get a count of documents that have the searched username in them. I'm assuming MongoDB would have a way of doing this (at least I'm hoping so). If not, then I guess I'd have to get all the records and manually count them within my express code? Which I hope I don't have to do because that will hurt performance as this website scales.

Here is the code of what I have currently.

```
payload = {Username: req.query.Username}
console.log(payload)
    if (req.query.Username) {
        dbo
        .snapUpvotesMongo()
        .countDocuments(payload,function(err, result) {
            if (err) { throw err; }
            else { res.send(result) }
        })

    }
```

Based on the console log there, I know that the payload is formatted as "{ Username: 'test' }"

When I copy it into MongoDB Compass and run it through the collection, it returns the expected results. So that part is correct.

But when I run the above code, I get the below error:

```
Successfully connected to MongoDB.
Server is running on port: 3050
src\routes\routes.js:303:24
node:_http_server:274
    throw new ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE(originalStatusCode);
    ^

RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: 7
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (node:_http_server:274:11)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (C:\Users\Brandon\Documents\GitHub\be-api\node_modules\on-headers\index.js:44:26)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (C:\Users\Brandon\Documents\GitHub\be-api\node_modules\on-headers\index.js:44:26)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (node:_http_server:265:8)
    at ServerResponse.end (node:_http_outgoing:871:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Brandon\Documents\GitHub\be-api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:232:10)
    at C:\Users\Brandon\Documents\GitHub\be-api\src\routes\routes.js:303:24
    at C:\Users\Brandon\Documents\GitHub\be-api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:371:9
    at C:\Users\Brandon\Documents\GitHub\be-api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:71:66 {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I've tried using .count() instead of .countDocuments and that doesn't appear to work either. So I must be misunderstanding something as to why this isn't returning anything.

I've also tried using .filter(), and putting my payload in there, but when I do that, I get the error "filter is not a function", which I assume is happening because of .countDocuments (since different routes in the same file use .filter, so I know it at least exists LOL)

I couldn't find much useful info to answer this when I looked around, so hoping someone else has ran into this before. (note that I am using Express-JS and to interface with MongoDB, I'm using the package "mongodb": "^4.9.0",

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a number to `res.send()`:

```
res.send(result)
```

Because it's a number, Express will interpret it as a HTTP status code and 7 (the number of matching documents) isn't valid (although I'm pretty sure that using `res.send(Number, …)` has been deprecated for a while now; I guess the Express developers have tried to maintain backward compatibility).

Instead, make sure you pass it as a string:

```
res.send(String(result))
```